# How can I get group members from an AD group that only contains security groups?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have 3 groups (HR, COMPT and FIN) and their groups contains only security groups.
How do I extract their members of their groups?

```
$Groups = 
@"
GroupNames;
HR
COMPT
FIN
"@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

#HR has 3 security groups
#COMPT has 5 security groups
#FIN has 2 security groups
### I want to know how can I get their members ###

foreach ($Group in $Groups){
#Save-File to this Path
$Path = "C:\Temp\"

$group.GroupNames | Get-ADGroupMember | select name -ExpandProperty Name | ForEach-Object { 
Get-ADGroup $_ -Properties Members | select Name |
#Export CSV
Export-Csv -Path (Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath ('{0}.csv' -f $group.Name)) -NoTypeInformation -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8

  }
}
```

Comment: Are you interested in knowing which group a user belongs to? If not, `Get-ADGroupMember` has a `-Recursive` switch

Comment: For example, my group HR contains 3 groups (role_a, role_b and role_c). I want to know who is member of these 3 groups.

Comment: Ah right, then `-Recursive` wouldn't work in that case, all right, if nobody post an answer I'll post in a few. But, as far as I remember, you mentioned on your other question that the members of your groups could be from different domains, are these those groups? If so, your current script does not work

Comment: These groups are from the same domain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try something like this, first you loop through the groups on the CSV (**Parents**), then for each parent you query their `Member` attribute (**Child Groups**) and for each child you query their `Member` attribute which should be in this case *users objects*. This would give you a report of each **Parent Group** and their **Child Groups** and their **Members**.

```
# CSV Should have a `GroupNames` column!!
$groups = Import-Csv /path/to/parentGroups.csv

$result = foreach($parent in $groups.GroupNames) {
    $parentGroup = Get-ADGroup $parent -Properties Member
    foreach($child in $parentGroup.Member) {
        # NOTE: This assumes the Members of Parent are GROUPS!
        $childGroup = Get-ADGroup $child -Properties Member
        foreach($member in $childGroup.Member) {
            $member = Get-ADObject $member
            [pscustomobject]@{
                ParentGroup = $parentGroup.SamAccountName
                ChildGroup  = $childGroup.SamAccountName
                Member      = $member.SamAccountName
                ObjectClass = $member.ObjectClass
            }
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv ..... -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Ok ill try it tomorrow when i get back to work. Thank you!!

Comment: I used this command below and it works fine :)

Comment: Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $group.grounames | ?{$_.ObjectClass -eq "Group"} | %{Write-Host $_.Name;Get-ADGroupMember $_ }

Comment: @ak2595 Yup that works, but that won't tell you the `ParentGroup` and `ChildGroup`. If you're interested only in the members and not knowing which group they belong to then that's fine